# Show error message if user inputs incorrect IP Address for server

Tags: c#, exception, server, client, ip-address

I have a client/server app where the user needs to input the IP Address of the server in order to connect to it. If the user inputs something other than an IP address I get an unhandled exception. If the user inputs the wrong IP address the app freezes completely and has to be force-closed.

I've managed to use a try-catch to get a friendly error message to pop up if the user inputs something other than an IP Address (instead of showing the unhandled exception error), which allows them to try again. But I can't figure out how to get the same message box to pop up if the user enters an IP address, but it's the wrong IP address (to avoid the program freezing).

Here's a snippet showing my connection process:

```
        try
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"/ServerIP.cfg", ServerIPbox.Text);
            string ServerIP = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"/ServerIP.cfg");
            serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ServerIP), 8888);
        }

        catch (FormatException)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid IP address");
            return;
        }
        catch (SocketException)
        {
            return;
        }
```

In my client app; the user enters the IP address of the machine that the server app is running on into a textbox and then either presses enter or clicks on a connect button to start the try block.

I'm pretty new to C# so I'm not sure if it's possible; but ideally I'd like the client to be able to check if the IP address that was entered is actually the IP address of the server before attempting to connect to it. That way I could avoid the exception altogether, and it just seems like it would be the proper way to do it, rather than hiding an error message behind a friendly pop-up.

---

**EDIT:** I've tried using Darshan Patel's answer, but I'm running into some issues. First, here's my code:

```
private void ConnectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"/ServerIP.cfg", ServerIPbox.Text);
                string ServerIP = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"/ServerIP.cfg");
        try
        {
            var myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ServerIP);
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ServerIP), 8888);

                //CONNECT TO SERVER

                Client.Connect(serverEndPoint);
                SendMessage("Client Connected (" + DateTime.Now + ")");
            }
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect : " + ex.Message);                
        }
```

Now I get the "Unable to connect.." message every time I click the ConnectButton, regardless if I've successfully connected or not.

Also, after getting the "Unable to connect.." message, my code continues to run, instead of staying where it was and allowing the user to try and input the correct IP address.

---

**EDIT 2:** Here is another attempt at modifying my original code:

```
private void ConnectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        try
        {
            //ATTEMPT TO CONNECT TO SERVER
            serverEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ServerIPbox.Text), 8888);
            Client.Connect(serverEndPoint);
        }

        //INCORRECT IP ADDRESS WAS ENTERED
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid IP address");
            return;
        }

        //SUCCESSFULLY CONNECTED TO SERVER
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"/ServerIP.cfg", ServerIPbox.Text);
```

In this attempt my code catches anything that isn't an IP address and stops it before it gets written to the "ServerIP.cfg" file, and displays the "Invalid IP Address" message, allowing the user to try again.

Once the user inputs an IP address, it get's saved to the "ServerIP.cfg" file and (ideally) they are connected to the server.

The only issue with this is; if the user inputs an IP address, but it's not the IP of the machine the server is running on, the app stops responding.

The app also stops responding if the user inputs any combination of 9 numbers (which it seems the program thinks is an IP address)

I need a reliable method of checking whether or not the IP address (or 9 numbers) that the user has entered is, in fact, the correct IP address of the machine the server is running on before letting the program attempt to connect to it. This way I can stop the app from freezing upon an unsuccessful connection attempt.

Comment: IP address point to server ?

Comment: If you're asking "does the IP address point to the server?" the answer is yes.

Comment: what is output of ServerIP ???

Comment: ServerIP is the IP address the user enters into a textbox.text, I save it to ServerIP.cfg so they don't have to type in their IP address each time they log in to the client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this function :

```
System.Net.NetworkInformation;

public static bool PingHost(string nameOrAddress)
{
    bool pingable = false;
    Ping pinger = new Ping();
    try
    {
        PingReply reply = pinger.Send(nameOrAddress);
        pingable = reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
    }
    catch (PingException)
    {
        // Discard PingExceptions and return false;
    }
    return pingable;
}
```

The above could be used as :

```
private void button9_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string serverIP = "192.168.3.213";
        bool result = PingHost(serverIP);
        if (result)
        {
            // connected successfully 
            // do the core logic here
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect to server!, Check your Server IP address");
        }

    }
```

The function PingHost is a part of the class , and same is being called in the button click . If it's unreachable it will pop-up the message .

Comment: How would I use this method to tell my client whether it's allowed to connect to the particular IP address or not? ie. In what part of your function would I insert the code that tells my client to connect to the IP address?

Comment: You are getting the Ip from a Server.cgf file . just pass it to the Function PingHost(IPADRESS) . If pinghostreturn true .  it's all done . else if it return false print a message to user

Comment: Sorry to sound like such a noob, but do I need to put the function in its own method, or just inside a class?

Comment: Would you mind showing me an example of how to write that function to work with my code?

Comment: I have edited the answer to make it simple, and it always good to ask doubts ,

Comment: I'm still having some issues with it, do I need to change `nameOrAddress` to `ServerIP`? Also, when I try to add the function, I get red underlined errors for `Ping`, `PingReply`, `IPStatus`, and `PingException`. Do I need to first declare them somewhere?

Comment: Sorry, I was just missing `using System.Net.NetworkInformation;` I think it may be fixed now, I'll report back in a minute

Comment: Works! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try [ping operation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (with timeout) before doing actual connect. Other work around could be  set connect timeout property if you are using tcp connection.

Answer (score 0):

try below code it may help you

```
try
{
    var myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.0.1");
    // Here "http://192.168.0.1" is your server ip address.
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();

    if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Connected");
        // do your stuff.
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Unable to connect : " + ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: Will this work with an unknown server IP address? The user needs to input their server's IP address because the app doesn't know it yet. In this case, I would have to replace "http://192.168.0.1" with my `(ServerIP)` string. Should that work okay?

Comment: ServerIP is the IP address the user enters into a textbox.text, I save it to ServerIP.cfg so they don't have to type in their IP address each time they log in to the client